# fixed position in iphone

Tags: html, css, position, sticky-footer

The fixed position for the footer isworking in browser bt it is not working in iphone.

```
 <div class="footer">
        <input name="" type="submit" id="submit" value="send" />
   </div>
```

Css is,

```
.footer{
position:fixed; 
bottom:0; 
left:0; 
width:100%; 
margin:0 auto; 
padding:6px 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use the same web browser ? (safari on iphone)

Comment: What isn't working? Can you show us a picture, both with and without the issue? Your code looks fine as it is there.

Comment: yes. in iphone the footer is fixing to the middle of the page

Comment: Your code seems just fine, maybe the browser version ? (You are right sam but i don't see the add comment button at the bottom of the question =(

Answer (score 0):

position:fixed only works on IOS5+

Comment: if you see other sites with a fixed footer on IOS4, etc, they use js